# Remove key from default profile yml in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, configuration-files

I have a Spring Boot `application.yml` file structured as:

```
mapValues:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
```

Now I want to run the application in another profile where those key/value should be replaced with different keys in `application-profile.yml` as:

```
mapValues:
    key3: value3
    key4: value4
```

Spring seems to be merging these two yml profiles automatically and the application sees:

```
mapValues:
    key1: value1
    key2: value2
    key3: value3
    key4: value4
```

I do not want to keep `key1` and `key`, instead just keep `key3` and `key4`. How can this be achieved?

Comment: It should work, if both of them are in separate profiles and at one time, you activate only one.

Comment: The first one is in the default profile with application.yml. There does not seem to be a way to completely replace the map value supplied from the default profile.

Comment: So, if first one is default, `key1` and `key2` should be `null` when you activate the profile. These two keys should not have any values

Comment: That's not what I am seeing. Those keys with their values remain. I can potentially change the value of those keys in default profile with the new profile but cannot seem to remove those keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you specify in your application.yml file defaults to all profiles. If you want to separate properties, create multiple yml files, like application-dev.yml and application-test.yml and specify the profile explicitly like below (typically in bootstrap.yml)

```
spring:
  profiles:
    active: test
```

With the above profile set, your app will see the properties in application.yml and application-test.yml files only. Properties in application-dev.yml will not be available.

Comment: you can use application-default.yml for default profile